# Can one use maven's prepare release with a github protected branch?

Tags: java, maven, github, jenkins, gnupg

Okay, either one cannot do this, or I'm missing something.

TL;DR version:

In a Jenkins pipeline, I want to do a `mvn release:prepare` on a project that has protected branch rules requiring signed commits for ALL users, but that only (seemingly) does git commit .... without signing.  Is it possible to use the plugin with signed commits?

Long version:

My Jenkins server is set up to spawn agents in the cloud and perform steps there.  My dev team (Java) wants to use the maven-release-plugin to handle new releases.  We have a beanch protection rule in place in our github repos that require signed commits for **all** branches and **all** users, no exceptions.

Everything works fine until we get to the step where we attempt `mvn release:prepare` as it *seems* to only perform a git commit that is **NOT** signed, despite a .gitconfig that says a) always do a signed commit and b) use this gpg key to do that op with.

I have the following gitconfig settings for the user running jenkins:

```
[alias]                                                             
  commit = commit -S                                                
[user]                                                             
  email = [REDACTED]                                        
  name = CICDUser                                                
  signingkey = [REDACTED]             
[commit]                                                            
  gpgsign = true                                                    
[tag]                                                               
  gpgsign = true                                                    
  forceSignAnnotated = true                                         
[gpg]                                                               
  program = gpg2
```

I also have gpg configuration to use pinentry loopback, use the agent and to read the secret from a file on the filesystem.  Gpg agent's config is set to allow the pinentry loopback.  Yes, I know, bad idea to store the passphrase on the filesystem.  If it's any consolation, these agents are spun up for the build, and then destroyed at the end.

Either way, it's my understanding that git *should* honor its config, unless maven isn't really calling out to git but using some builtin implementation.  Assuming it's the latter, or it's clobbering/ignoring my options somehow, is there a way to tell the plugin to sign commits?

TIA, as always.

Edited to add

The java project is using:

```
maven-release plugin 3.0.0-M4
openjdk 8
Jenkins 2.319.1
gnupg 2.2.27
libcrypt 1.8.8
git 2.30.2
```

Now... jenkins output.

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build Setup)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $FILE
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ cp **** /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] sh
+ ssh-keyscan github.com
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-17a926d7
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-17a926d7
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-17a926d7
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-17a926d7
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-17a926d7
[Pipeline] sh
+ gpg --export-ownertrust
+ sed s/:.*/:5:/
+ gpg --import-ownertrust
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo hello
+ gpg2 --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

hello
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=kEmN
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
[Pipeline] sh
+ git config --global -l
user.email=[REDACTED]
user.name=CICDUser
user.signingkey=B5FE4B265A382845B45D32D6506F61238204C2F0
commit.gpgsign=true
tag.gpgsign=true
tag.forcesignannotated=true
gpg.program=gpg2
[Pipeline] sh
+ gpg2 --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-12-28 [SC]
      B5FE4B265A382845B45D32D6506F61238204C2F0
uid           [ unknown] CICDUser <[REDACTED]>
sub   rsa4096 2021-12-28 [E]

[Pipeline] sh
+ echo this is a test
[Pipeline] sh
+ git add .
[Pipeline] sh
+ git commit -S -mTesting
[test fd220d0] Testing
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test_file.txt
[Pipeline] sh
+ git push --set-upstream origin test
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.3' to the list of known hosts.
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/test.        
remote: error: Commits must have valid signatures.        
To github.com:[REDACTED].git
 ! [remote rejected] test -> test (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:[REDACTED]'
```

Comment: The maven plugin will honor local git configuration. You must have an issue there.

Comment: Can't you spawn an agent with same config and run some git commands manually to debug?

Comment: Log file output... which release plugin version? etc. more information ...

Comment: @GaëlJ, see the above.  

Note that I have also added the no-tty to the gpg.conf, thinking it may be something to do with a lack of a proper tty in the container.

Last, but not least, I have tried calling ```git commit``` with the -S flag, with no luck there.